# Create a dictionary of subcubes from larger cube in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am examining every contiguous 8 x 8 x 8 cube within a 50 x 50 x 50 cube.  I am trying to create a collection (in this case a dictionary) of the subcubes that contain the same sum and a count of how many subcubes share that same sum.  So in essence, the result would look something like this:

{key = sum, value = number of cubes that have the same sum}

{256 : 3, 119 : 2, ...}

So in this example, there are 3 cubes that sum to 256 and 2 cubes that sum to 119, etc.  Here is the code I have thus far, but it only sums (at least I think it does):

```
an_array = np.array([i for i in range(500)])
cube = np.reshape(an_array, (8, 8, 8))

c_size = 8 # cube size
sum = 0
idx = None

for i in range(cube.shape[0] - cs + 2):
     for j in range(cube.shape[1] - cs + 2):
          for k in range(cube.shape[2] - cs + 2):
          cube_sum = np.sum(cube[i:i + cs, j:j + cs, k:k + cs])
          new_list = {cube_sum : ?}
```

What I am trying to make this do is iterate the cube within cubes, sum all cubes then count the cubes that share the same sum.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use `from collections import defaultdict`, then create the `dict` outside the loops (`result = defaultdict(int)`) and then update it using `result[sum] += 1 `. If a key doesn't exist in `defaultdict`, it will be made and get the value 0 (from the `int`).

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate.  So I would step out of for loop and dict(result = defaultdict(int))) and increment the counter?  Thank you!

Comment: I wrote it down as an answer, so you have some example code.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict

an_array = np.array([i for i in range(500)])
cube = np.reshape(an_array, (8, 8, 8))

c_size = 8 # cube size
sum = 0
idx = None
result = defaultdict(int)

for i in range(cube.shape[0] - cs + 2):
     for j in range(cube.shape[1] - cs + 2):
          for k in range(cube.shape[2] - cs + 2):
          cube_sum = np.sum(cube[i:i + cs, j:j + cs, k:k + cs])
          result[cube_sum] += 1
```

#### Explanation

The `defaultdict(int)`, can be read as a `result.get(key, 0)`. Which means that if a key doesn't exists it will be initialized with 0. So the line `result[cube_sum] += 1`, will either contain 1, or add 1 to the current number of cube_sum.

Comment: Ah, I misread what you said originally. Understand now and thank you!  It worked just fine.